# Any downsides on using Multisite for many look-alike-websites?

Tags: multisite

I'm developing multiple websites for a photographer. Most of the time I build a custom design around these wonderful images the photographer makes, but in many cases the companies don't have the budget to let us build a custom designed WP site. So I'm looking for a easy way to offer my clients a 'template'. A basic website, which I setup, customize a little, as a service for our clients.

So here's my idea:

- I make a theme, and every new website has its own child theme with some minor modifications. All websites are structure-wise identical, but I adjust logo's, colors, fonts and the general look-and-feel.
- Each website has its own domain, so no subdomains involved.
- They all share some plugins like GravityForms. This seems a mayor advantage for me: I only have to update one installation, and all  clients are up to date.

Do you see any downsides, pitfalls? I want to prevent setting this whole thing up, and ending up with an unmanageable system.

Answer (score 5):

The main rule of thumb that I follow in these cases is: "Use WordPress multisite if it gives you clear advantages, not just because you can".

Mike Epstein explained this pretty well in the "[Don't use WordPress Multisite](http://halfelf.org/2011/dont-use-wordpress-multisite/)" post.

This question is also answered on Quora before: [Are there any disadvantages to using wordpress Multisite?](http://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-disadvantages-to-using-wordpress-Multisite) and I believe that covers most pros and cons of WordPress multisite as well.

Your use case, which holds a couple very similar websites, is clearly one where it has mostly only advantages to use multisite.

BUT: Important to note, is that not all plugins are compatible (or working 100%) in WordPress multisite. Some have obvious bugs because the developer never bothered to test.

Finally, one important thing: You can always export one of the websites that deviates too far from the 'standard' within your multisite and set that up as a standalone install.